# How is this user defined data type type-casted?

Tags: java, android, type-conversion

```
Button buttonClick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button)
```

Applying Java grammar, the above statement means the value returned by method
**findViewById()** is *changed* to the data type **Button**, and stored in variable **buttonClick**.

I've studied Java(apparently not enough!), and have never come across type casting a user-defined data type. 
How does this work?

Comment: It works the same as any other casting.  It doesn't matter who wrote the class.

Comment: This works because Button extends View, which is returned from findViewById

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting @nikis response into code:

```
public class View extends Object {...}
public class Label extends View {...}
public class Button extends View {...}

public View findViewById(String id) {...}

//normal assignment
View v = findViewById(viewID); 

//implicit casting to base class
Object o = findViewById(objectID); 

//compile time error because the return might not be a Button
Button b = findViewById(buttonID);

//explicit cast forces compiler to treat the return as a Button
//if the return is not a Button, then ClassCastException is trown at runtime
Button bb = (Button)findViewById(buttonID);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is explicit casting, it works because `Button` class extends `View` class which is return type of `findViewById` method. You should use explicit casting for downstream casting, because it is not safe. You can use explicit cast between any objects in Java, but if this cast actually not possible you'll get `ClassCastException` at the runtime. On the other hand, there is implicit casting, which is always safe, so there is no need to declare it. Implicit casting is upstream casting, for example from `View` to `Object`.